# How to uninstall 'AMPPS' stack on a machine running on 'Windows 10 Home Single Language ' operating system?

Tags: windows, windows-10, php, uninstall, ampps

I'm using a machine running on **'Windows 10 Home Single Language'** 64-bit operating system.

I just installed **AMPPS stack** on this machine by downloading the installer from URL : `http://ampps.com/downloads` but now I want to uninstall this **AMPPS stack**.

I tried to find our uninstall option for AMPPS stack but couldn't found it anywhere.

So can someone please me by providing a way to uninstall this **AMPPS stack**?

Thanks.